# "How to debug ‘server side code’ in Powerbuilder”

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a powerbuilder application and it is 3 tier architecture. The business objects are written in server side. How to debug the server side scripts? I tried to insert the break point in the server side calling function from the client side script. But it is not step into the server side script.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to instantiate the objects locally and debug them that way.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.I am new in pb especially in server side.Could you explain in little bit detail?My application business functionalities are in server side.There is a big bunch of code in server side, especially checking database values and all.Are you saying if i am instantiating the object in client side,it will redirect to the server side?

Comment: No, instantiate the object locally instead of in the server so that you can debug it in the normal way. Then once the problem is fixed, deploy to the server.